# C program to print Pascal's triangle

Tags: c

Worked 2 hours on this. It print Pascal's triangle. Change `MAX_LEN` to any desired triangle size. What do you think about the quality of the code?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>


int main() {
        const unsigned int MAX_LEN = 20;
        unsigned char rowNum, rowWidth, rowOffset, i;
        unsigned int *numPointer, *num;
        unsigned int maxNum = 0;

        for (char len = 1; len <= MAX_LEN; len++)
            maxNum += len;
        num = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)*maxNum);
        if (num == NULL)
            return 1;

        for (rowNum = 0; rowNum < MAX_LEN; rowNum++) {
            rowOffset = 0;
            for (i = 0; i <= rowNum; i++) {
                rowOffset += i;
            }
            num[rowOffset] = 1;
            for (i = 1; i < rowNum; i++) {
                num[rowOffset + i] = num[rowOffset + i - rowNum] + num[rowOffset + i - rowNum - 1];
            }
            num[rowOffset + rowNum] = 1;
        }

    numPointer = num;
    for (rowNum = 0; rowNum < MAX_LEN; rowNum++) {
        for (rowWidth = 0; rowWidth <= rowNum; rowWidth++) {
            printf_s("  %d  ", *numPointer);
            numPointer++;
        }
        printf_s("\n");
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to consider:

1. `for (char len = 1; len <= MAX_LEN; len++)` is extremely dangerous as you could easily overflow `len` here since `MAX_LEN` has type `unsigned`. Currently, the value of `MAX_LEN` is 20, and your code is safe; however, if you decide to change this value at any point, you will likely overflow `len` here, leading to undefined behavior either because of overflow of a signed type if `char` is signed or because of the fact that infinite loops (into which this one will turn) that do not do IO are ub in the case of an unsigned `char` type.
2. In C, you do not need to cast the return value of `malloc`. Simple assignment will do. In fact, don't actively cast the return value of malloc because it clutters your code with casts, which is a symptom of bad code in general, and can hide a bug related to implicit functions (only before C11).
3. Actually, that loop from point 1 I mentioned can be removed altogether. This follows from recognizing that you are adding all integer values starting from one up to `MAX_LEN`, for which there is an easy to compute formula: `S = n(n + 1)/2`. Translated into code, this would be

   ```
   maxNum = MAX_LEN * (MAX_LEN + 1) / 2;
   ```

   which is not only shorter, but also more efficient to compute.
4. Why do you define almost all your variables at the top of your function, although they are not used until much later? This is a bad practice, because it increases the mental load everyone reading your code has to deal with. I don't want to remember the types of eight or nine different variables while focusing on code that doesn't even use them. Just define them right were they need to be defined.
5. Overall, you use `char` too much. Only use `char` when you are working with characters or single bytes, otherwise use `int`, `unsigned` and everything larger or equal in bit size. You are not gaining anything through your use of `char` except a high chance to trigger ub several times over in your code (You are likely not even saving space because of alignment concerns on most common modern platforms.)
6. Don't `printf` a single character; that's wasteful. Use `putchar` for that.
7. Don't include `stdafx.h`. Unless you have a concrete compilation performance concern, it won't do anything for you. And even then, it is not standard, and most people who use compiler other than MSVC will likely complain about it.
8. Split your code up into functions. `main()` is not the right place to write problem-solving code, only to put things together. Do yourself a favor and organize your code a little more, it will help you keep a good overview over which part does what and make other readers not turn away on sight of that huge `main` god-function.